# Android NDK difference between \r\n vs \n

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, java-native-interface, clang

I need to add \r\n characters inside a character array in C file.

I added `const char *val="Hello\r\nhii";`

But, I couldn't print this string, getting blank line initially and 'hii' only printing.

Why this is? Can I add \r character?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 , Compilers GCC 4.9 and clang.

Comment: It's not clear from your question _how_ you're attempting to print that string.

Comment: I created a macro definition for Android NDK Log method like this:

#define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

And after I invoked like this :

 LOGD("%s",val);